# Problems with Hibernate Criteria API (Disjunction and Conjunction)

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria-api

I have a problem with using `Conjunction`s and `Disjunction`s. My program receives an arbitrary number of filter elements (each representing a `Criterion`) from the ui and is intended to chain together them as an `AND` or `OR`.

So for example I can have 3 elements like this (I represent a `Criterion` with a letter):

```
a OR b AND c
```

My code looks like this:

```
    // ...
    Criteria rootCriteria = createCriteria(entityClass);
    Conjunction conjunction = Restrictions.conjunction();
    Disjunction disjunction = Restrictions.disjunction();
    boolean isFirst = true;
    for (InternalFilterElement element : elements) {
        if (isFirst) {
            isFirst = false;
            rootCriteria.add(createCriterion(element.getFilterRelation(), element.getValue()));
        } else if (InternalFilterOperand.AND.equals(element.getInternalFilterOperand())) {
            addCriterionToJunction(conjunction, element);
        } else {
            addCriterionToJunction(disjunction, element);
        }
    }
    rootCriteria.add(disjunction);
    rootCriteria.add(conjunction);
    // ...
```

My problem is that I always get `a AND b AND c` and some unnecessary parentheses.

***What I really wish to know is that I am using the wrong tool for this task or not? How can I mix `AND` and `OR` operators?***

**edit**

`InternalFilterOperand` is basically an `enum` containing `OR` and `AND`

`addCriterionToJunction` just adds a `Criterion` to the `Junction` based on the relation (<, >, ...) and the value. It does not have any side effects.

Comment: What is `InternalFilterOperand`? Also can you please share your `addCriterionToJunction`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By using the following code, you mix AND and OR operators in Hibernate:

```
    Criteria rootCriteria = createCriteria(entityClass);
    rootCriteria.add(Restrictions.or(
            Restrictions.eq("a","a"),
            Restrictions.and(
                    Restrictions.eq("b","b"),
                    Restrictions.eq("c","c")
            )
    ));
```

This example results in the following output: a=a OR b=b AND c=c without the parenthesis you would get with conjunction and disjunction.

Comment: Would this work?:

 Criterion ANDORs=null;

        if(ANDORs==null){
            if(grupo.getOperadorLogico().equals(PesquisaFiltroOperadorLogico.AND)){
                ANDORs= Restrictions.conjunction();
            }else{
                ANDORs = Restrictions.disjunction();
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

You're making it harder than necessary. Why not just use the following:

```
Junction junction = 
    InternalFilterOperand.AND.equals(element.getInternalFilterOperand()) ? 
        Restrictions.conjunction() : 
        Restrictions.disjunction();
for (InternalFilterElement element : elements) {
    addCriterionToJunction(junction, element);
}
rootCriteria.add(junction);
```

Comment: I already tried that out. Does not work either. Every `InternalFilterElement` contains an OR or an AND so I can't decide which one to use outside the loop.

Answer (score -1):

I am close to believe that `InternalFilterOperand` is not set correctly in your `elements` as everything else looks right.

Please print/debug the `element.getInternalFilterOperand()` values in your loop as first statement to verify and correct.

**EDIT:** Try adding `conjunction/disjunction` directly in the `rootCriteria`

```
for (InternalFilterElement element : elements) {
  if (isFirst) {
      isFirst = false;
      rootCriteria.add(
                 createCriterion(element.getFilterRelation(), element.getValue()));
  }else if (InternalFilterOperand.AND.equals(element.getInternalFilterOperand())){
        //add debugg/sys out: adding conjunction
        System.out.println("adding conjunction");
        rootCriteria.add(Restrictions.conjunction().add(element));
  } else {
        //add debugg/sys out: adding disjunction
        System.out.println("adding disjunction");
        rootCriteria.add(Restrictions.disjunction().add(element));
  }
}
```

Comment: I overrode toString() in my `InternalFilterElement` and if I read through `elements` it prints out something like this: "null foo = bar and wom = bat or baz = bar". The first element does not contain an operand but that's fine.

Comment: Do me a favor, add these as very first statements in your `for` loop and share the output. `System.out.println(InternalFilterOperand.AND); System.out.println(element.getInternalFilterOperand()); System.out.println(InternalFilterOperand.AND.equals(element.getInternalFilterOperand()));`

Comment: I already shared that in my previous comment. What I really wish to know is this: "How can I mix AND and OR operators?"

Comment: What you shared is little different than what I am looking. I am 99% sure, that problem is somewhere in your comparison as its always getting true.

Comment: Nope I debugged that. This code added elements to both `conjuncion` and `disjunction` (in the correct order).

Comment: Not sure. Try adding `conjunction/disjunction` directly in the `rootCriteria`. I updated the answer.